# Given a set and an equivalence relation find the equivalence classes and the quotient set

Tags: equivalence-relations, set-partition

Given $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ in $A\times A$ we define $$(x; y)R(z; t)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad x + t = y + z.$$ Find the equivalence classes and the quotient set.

---

I tried to find the equivalence classes:

Let $(x_0,y_0)\in A\times A$. The class to which it belongs $(x_0,y_0)$ is $$C[(x_0,y_0)]=\{(x,y)\in A\times A:(x,y)R(x_0,y_0)\}=\{(x,y)\in A\times A:x+y_0=y+x_0\}.$$

Is it all right up here? Because then I do not know how to continue. Maybe passing the generic elements $ x_0, y_0 $ to a member? If I do not know the equivalence classes, I can not know the whole quotient. Some help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** rewrite the condition $x+t=y+z$ as $$x-y=z-t$$

The value of $x-y$ can be anything between $-4$ and $4$, so there are $9$ equivalence classes.

---

*Geometrical interpretation: an equivalence class is a set of points all lying on the same line with slope $1$.*

Comment: Hmm so the generic class of equivalence would be $C[(x_0,y_0)]=\{(x,y)\in A\times A:x-y=x_0-y_0\}$? (I do not understand why the value $x-y$ should go in a range between $-4$ to $4$). I shouldn't write the equivalence classes by extension, but by understanding.

Comment: @manooooh I don't follow your comment... Do you recognize why the equivalence class of $(3,2)$ is for example $\{(5,4),(4,3),(3,2),(2,1)\}$ since these are all of the possible pairs whose first element is larger than the second element by one?  The way you write it in your comment just now seems like the easiest way to write it to me, what else would you be after in an answer?

Comment: @manooooh as for why the value of $x-y$ goes in a range between $-4$ and $4$... recognize that the smaller the first number is and the larger the second number, the smaller the possible result, so the smallest possible result would be for the pair $(1,5)$ which results in $1-5=-4$.  Similarly the largest will be for the pair $(5,1)$...

Comment: @manooooh on top of what JMoravitz said, the geometrical interpretation that I gave you allows you to "understand without writing extensively" as you asked.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for your patience. I think I understand you: for example the equivalence class of $(4,2)$ is $\{(3,1),(4,2),(5,3)\}$, right? If so, then the generic class of the relationship that I wrote as a comment is correct.

Comment: @manooooh Absolutely.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Thank you for your time. So the geometric interpretation you give are points that form infinite lines ($y = mx + b$) where all are parallel, with slope $ 1 $ ($m = 1$)? And that is the quotient set, no?

Comment: @manooooh Not really infinite lines: only the intersection of these lines with $A\times A$. But then yes, that is the quotient set.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Oh yes what a fool I am (thought the set was $\mathbb N^2$). Anddd... So how can the quotient set be analytically written? Maybe $ A \times A / R = \{(x,y)\in A\times A:y=x+y_0,\; y_0\in A\}$?

Comment: Sorry I mean $A \times A / R = \{(x_0,y_0)\in A\times A:y_0=x_0+y,\; y\in A\}$

Comment: @manooooh not exactly, $y$ doesn't lie in $A$ but in $\{-4, \ldots , 4\}$. Also, there should be two couples of $\{ \ \}$: you've started writing **one** equivalence class here. The $y\in A$ should be outside.

Comment: Yeah, so the last part would be "$y\in\{-4,\ldots,4\}$". Thank you @ArnaudMortier !

Comment: @manooooh Yes: $\{\{\text{what you wrote, without $y\in A$}\}, y\in A\}$

Comment: (Ok, but we said you should not go $y\in A $ but $y\in \{- 4, \ldots, 4\} $). I thought that the possible values that could take a variable should be within the $\{\}$ (as for example the set of even numbers, which would be the set $\{x\in\mathbb Z:x=2k,\;k\in\mathbb Z\}$ and not  $\{\{x\in\mathbb Z:x=2k\},\;k\in\mathbb Z\}$). Thank you very much!

Comment: @manooooh oh sorry my bad, I wrote $y\in A$ without thinking. It is $\{\{\text{what you wrote, without $y\in A$}\},y\in\{-4, \ldots, 4\}\}$.